# How to send message to a specific logged in user using spring web sockets

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I will be using mongodb to store my chats between users.
I have assigned a UUID to each user when he signups, and after login each user gets a JWT token for session authentication.

#### Use Case:

User will first send a chat request to a user he wants to chat. If a user accepts the chat request then they can to 1-1 chat.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatWS") // ws connection url
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
         registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")// to send data to ws
         .enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); // to subscribe for real time feed
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `convertAndSendToUser` method in `SimpMessageSendingOperations` class, which is  available in springframework to send a message to a specific user.

```
convertAndSendToUser(userName,"/topic/message", data);
```

Refer the following [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-send-message-to-user) for more details.

Comment: I am sending header via stompClient,  i need to read my header info for sender and reveicer uuid. How can i read that

Comment: ``   var header = {
        "sender-name" : "asd",
        "suuid":"bb2c9039-0ed3-4d6f-b078-db965286944d",
        "ruuid":"bb2c9039-0ed3-4d6f-b078-db965286944d"
    }

    stompClient.connect(header, onConnected, onError);`